# Error in output .cls and .tex files

Tags: resume, cv

1. Could not start the command
   pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
                .cls file

2.! LaTeX Error: File `res.cls' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \setlength

```
               .tex file
```

Comment: Welcome, please have a look at [the wikipage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae). There is a warning that the class you are trying to use is outdated and shouldn't be used anymore. Look out for an alternative.

Comment: you surely did not get both of those errors at the same time? the first error says that latex could not start (usually because only an editor has been installed) but the second error comes from tex, so tex must have started...